# Bootstrap submenu placement error

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, submenu

The 2nd level of submenu is placed next the 1st level submenu's 1st element, when the lower elements of the 1st submenu which have lesser 2nd level submenu elements, the user cant navigate to the new 2nd level submenu due to the mouseover is gone out the menu.

How can i place the 2nd level submenu next to every 1st submenu's selected element?

Here is the JSFiddle, check elements and try to navigate to their submenu : memory devices, printers, laptop bags, projectors, etc.

HTML

```
Code too large to be displayed here. Check JSFiddle
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this rule :

```
.dropdown-menu > li { position: relative; }
```

what you need is the first level submenu to have `position: relative`, so that when the next level defines `position: absolute; top: 0;` its top is that of the immediate parent.